# Is Samba read/write rate performance on Ubuntu 20.04 capped at around 11MB/s?

Tags: samba, performance, file-sharing

I've noticed that no matter what I do, I can only get read/write performance of around 11MB/s with my Ubuntu 20.04 file server running Samba Version 4.11.6-Ubuntu using Ubuntu, MacOS 10.15, Windows 10 clients for a file of around 250GB.  If I share a folder on Windows, I can get above 100MB/s performance with the same clients and file size.  Is Samba just that bad compared to Windows?  It's pretty consistently around 10x slower on Ubuntu Samba.  I have a lightly loaded 1Gb/s LAN, so 100MB/s (1B=~8b) is about as good as you can do.  I've tried many conf commands in smb.conf.  I'm ready to give up and just host my file service on Windows.  Any last minute ideas before I make the change in Host?

---

```
# Performance improvement tips
log level = 1
#std#socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072 SO_KEEPALIVE
socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072 SO_KEEPALIVE IPTOS_THROUGHPUT

#no better than buf=131072#socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=2097152 SO_SNDBUF=2097152
# this one is really slow#socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_SNDBUF=8192 SO_RCVBUF=8192
read raw = Yes
write raw = Yes
strict locking = No
strict allocate = Yes
allocation roundup size = 4096
server signing = No
oplocks = yes
max xmit = 65535
dead time = 15
getwd cache = yes
#min receivefile size = 32768
min receivefile size = 16384
use sendfile = true
aio read size = 16384
aio write size = 16384
#aio read size = 32768
#aio write size = 32768
use sendfile = true

# Performance specific for MacOS
min protocol = SMB2
vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr  
fruit:metadata = stream
fruit:model = MacSamba
fruit:posix_rename = yes 
fruit:veto_appledouble = no
fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes 
fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the network performance degradation wasn't caused by SAMBA.   It was a general network bandwidth issue on a particular server's ethernet interface, caused by a large IPv4 IPTABLES rules file.